# PHP Script Running Twice

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

Ok so I have a weird problem. I have a local XAMPP running and running Acrylic DNS Proxy as well. While I was testing some code I noticed that it was running the script twice. Here's what I got.

**index.php**

```
<?php
$myFile = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "1\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**AcrylicHosts.txt**

```
127.0.0.1 test.com
127.0.0.1 *.test.com
```

**Vhost File**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/test
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias *.test.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /www/test
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias *.test.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl.key/server.key
    SSLProtocol TLSv1
</VirtualHost>
```

If you go to **test.com**, the text.txt output is "*1\n 1\n*"

But if you go to **www.test.com**, the text.txt output is "*1\n*"

Anyone know what to do to get it to stop running twice?

**Edit:**

These are the versions I'm working with:

```
Apache 2.4.4
MySQL 5.5.32
PHP 5.4.19
```

Comment: try this, and .. $ curl test.com/index.php

Comment: I believe test.com is calling twice which is the default behavior to run index.php. Kindly check your access_log if test.com is accessing twice. There could be redirect problem happening here

Comment: My Access log says
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 466
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1067
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 466  Do you think it could be because of the 404?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like it was because chrome was looking for favicon.ico (which caused a 404) and my .htaccess file points all 404s to index.php file which executed the code again.

Comment: Please mark this as an answer. This may help someone facing the same problem.

Comment: Wait, where is that .htaccess, i have the same problem and mayne this is the answer