# Strange & Insane PHP Bug, Page load after clearing browser history causes script to run multiple times

Tags: php, debugging, session, domdocument, libxml2

Basically I am creating a php framework for a University project
everything works except for a strange error making all PHP SESSION code duplicate after the request life cycle.

I have edited my original question, hopefully its simpler and more to the point.
I have done some further tests and now I can see what is happening but I cant understand why.

I am using DOMDocument for templating and it is RUNNING UNEXPECTED CODE
and causing the script to produce bizarre results by running any code related to the session after the script has ended.

Basically I am testing the sessions and the request life cycle with a simple counter function.

Here is the code and request life cycle:

```
//Session config from config file:
const SESSION = [
'name' => 'MAPSID',
'storage' => 'files',
'options' => [
    //'read_and_close' => true,
    'cookie_lifetime' => false,
    'use_strict_mode' => true,
    'use_only_cookies' => 1,
    'cookie_httponly' => 1,
    'use_trans_sid' => 0,
    //Ensure this is true for production:
    'cookie_secure' => false
    ],
];
session_name(SESSION['name']);

//index.php:
define('MAP_INITIALIZE', microtime(true));
require_once __DIR__.'/../env.php';
session_start(SESSION['options']);
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

//Set Session counter to 0 if not set
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
}

var_dump("SESSION count before increment:");
//Shows perfectly first time, then increments by 3, then by 2,
//Instead of one
var_dump($_SESSION['count']);

//Increment code which duplicates god knows where
$_SESSION['count']++;
var_dump($_SESSION['count']);

$app = map\factory\MapFactory::create_app();

$app->start(function ($request, $response){
    $response->capture(
        $request->route()
    );
    $response->send();
});

//App start method:
public function start(callable $initfunc=null)
{
    //Checks no illegal patterns in the URL, etc
    if ($this->request->is_valid()) {
        if (is_callable($initfunc)) {
            call_user_func_array(
                $initfunc,[$this->request, $this->response]
            );
        }
    }else{
        $this->response->invalid();
    }
}

//request is_valid:
public function is_valid(){
    if (filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)) {

        if ($url == '/') {
            return true;
        }

        if (!preg_match_all("/^\/[A-Za-z0-9\/\?\&\=\-\%]+$/", $url)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (preg_match_all("/\/\//", $url)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

//Route Request:
//I dont think this should matter as its the default index page,
no routes used
public function route()
{   
    $route = $this->create_router(new Router(
         $this->path,
         $this->client->user)
    );
    include APP.'/routes/routes.php';
    return $route->response();
}

//Capture response:
public function capture($res)
{
    if ($res === false) {
        $this->not_found();
    }elseif (is_string($res)) {

        //If I call this function, and then echo the response,
        //$_SESSION['count'] double increments,
        //and triple for the first request,
        $this->valid($response);

        //If I directly add the response without the valid method,
        //then the first refresh increments by 2 and then by 1
        //like so:
        $this->response = $res;//there is no error
    }elseif (is_null($response)) {
        echo "Deal with this later";
    } else {
        $this->invalid();
    }
}

//Valid response method:
public function valid($response)
{
    $mapdom = file_get_contents(APP.'/main.html');
    $mapdom = new HTMLDom($mapdom);
    $root = $mapdom->getElementById('root');
    $response = new HTMLDom($res);
    $domelem = $response->body->firstChild;
    $import = $mapdom->importNode($domelem, true);
    $root->appendChild($import);
    $mapdom->save_html();
    $this->response = $mapdom->dom;
}

//send response:
public function send(){
    foreach ($this->headers as $header) {
        header($header);
    }
    $this->response = 'some string';//No error
    echo $this->response;
}
```

Basically wen I use $this->valid() function the increment triples for the first request, then doubles,
If I dont use it it doubles for the first request and then increments by one,
There is obviously a pattern here, I am struggling to figure it out.
Tried using the debugger in PHPStorm, no error, its only the var_dump() output which is out of whack, makes me wonder, what is the error

I hope the question is not ambiguous, any advice would be greatly appreciated! Happy to provide full source code
Please can someone tell me where I am going wrong
Thanks

Comment: Do you have sessions set to auto start?  Or are you invoking `session_start();` anywhere else?  Have you checked your HTTP headers and confirmed you're receiving GET and/or POST (uppercase)?  Or that `$_SERVER['request_method']` is sending the correct value?  Is `Auth::form()` being invoked anywhere else?  Have you tried making that method non-static?

Comment: Also, what does `$app->response->send();` do?

Comment: Im going to create the wrapper class for Session handler and see if it fixes it

Comment: That function just echo out the response, I have added the code for it

Comment: var_dump(ini_get('session.auto_start')) returns 0, so I guess its not auto starting. I have got rid of Auth::form() for now as I will improve that function, Im using the simple counter code as it reproduces the same error, some how all code related to sessions duplicates, I cant understand why

Comment: Is all of this code in a single file, or is it separated into multiple files?  It's a bit difficult to follow the entire lifecycle because something like `Auth:form()` really shouldn't be in the same namespace as `App:foundation()`  Similarly, it's difficult to tell where `$request` is coming from, as well as what it has for attributes and data

Comment: No its all in separate files, I will add all the code of the life cycle if it helps

Comment: Another debugging tip - are you using an IDE?  If so, set breakpoints in your code and follow them through your lifecycle.  If you're a student, you can likely get free/cheap software.  It's a critical debugging tool, IMO.

Comment: Im using sublime text, I can start using PHPStorm,  I am clearing up the code and putting it all on here, so hopefully it can give a clear idea. I have followed the whole code, the session code is perfect until the end of the script, after refreshing the page, somehow the counter is already incrmented before it hits that line of code which should increment, then it somehow double increments

Comment: I have updated the code and included most of it except for routine functions which sanitize all the input in the request object constructor

Comment: getallheaders() does not show request method, but I get it in the Server super global and they are all capital, this only started happening after I started using DOMDocument

Comment: I have gone through the debugger in phpstorm, I cant see any errors, they increment correctly on the screen, I cant help but wonder why is the var_dump() incrementing by 2 every time only when I use the $this->valid() function in response'

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer my own question, I will say that I am so silly, but hopefully this might help others too.

When using any front-controller pattern or server redirect, I must make sure to keep a favicon.ico in the root of the public folder as browsers request this.
And since Apache redirects everything which is not a valid file to index.php, keeping a favicon.ico dummy file if not an actual image is crucial.

If this file is missing, apache will redirect this to index.php based on rewrite rules and this will cause the script to run again which can corrupt session variables and create unexpected issues and results because of something I would never in my wildest dreams have guessed would be linked to the problem, if it was not for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19761612/11995521